# Alias for root of a polynomial

Tags: symbolic, polynomials, series-expansion

I need to work with a variable $u$ such that $u^2 + u + 1 = 0$. I don't want to find a root of the polynomial $u^2 + u + 1$. Rather, I have to work with $u$ symbolically so that a (polynomial) expression in $u$ gets simplified using the equation $u^2 + u + 1 =0$.

For example, let

```
y = Series[u + 1 + u*x + x^2, {x, 0, 4}]
z = Series[u^2 + u^2*x + x^4, {x, 0, 4}]
```

Then, I'd expect

```
SeriesCoefficient[y+z, 0] = 0
SeriesCoefficient[y+z, 1] = -1
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm a Python/R user, this is unintelligible to me, can you explain without Mathematica jargon please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html)

```
assume = u^2 + u + 1 == 0;

y = Series[u + 1 + u*x + x^2, {x, 0, 4}];
z = Series[u^2 + u^2*x + x^4, {x, 0, 4}];

Assuming[assume, SeriesCoefficient[y + z, 0] // Simplify]

(* 0 *)

Assuming[assume, SeriesCoefficient[y + z, 1] // Simplify]

(* -1 *)
```

Comment: With `y = Series[u + 1 + x^2, {x, 0, 4}]` your method produces `u^2` for `Assuming[assume, SeriesCoefficient[y + z, 1] // Simplify]`. I think the expected result is `-1-u`.

Comment: @CarlWoll - I do not know what is "expected", but `LeafCount /@ {u^2, -1 - u}` indicates that `u^2` is simpler in the usual sense.

Answer (score 5):

You can give `u` an [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) for [`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power):

```
u /: u^n_Integer := Block[{u},
    If[n<0,
        PolynomialMod[(-u-1)^-n, 1+u+u^2],
        PolynomialMod[u^n,1+u+u^2]
    ]
]
```

Then:

```
y = Series[u + 1 + u x + x^2, {x, 0, 4}];
z = Series[u^2 + u^2 x + x^4,{x, 0, 4}];
```

and:

```
y + z //TeXForm
```

> $-x+x^2+x^4+O\left(x^5\right)$

Comment: Carl, what does the `Block[{u}, ...]` do here? I think I'm still confused about the usage of `Block`.

Comment: @Roman The Block is needed so that recursion is avoided (preventing evaluation of u^n on the right hand side)

Comment: I get Iteration limit exceeded with $1/u$.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest methods are usually the best. I suggest

```
rule = {u^n_ :> {1, u, -1 - u}[[Mod[n, 3] + 1]]};
y + z /. rule
```

which will do what you want. Also, the following code

```
Table[u^n, {n, 0, 6}] /. rule
```

demonstrates that $u^3 = 1$ and the powers of $u$ are periodic with period $3$.